# Are there functions whose integral from negative to positive infinity is a non-zero constant?

Tags: calculus

The only functions that I can think with a integral that is constant when evaluated from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ are functions of the form $ f(x) = \frac{k}{x^2 + a}$, in which case $\dots $

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) = 0.$

Of course we could define a piecewise function to be zero for most of the time, but are there any continuous functions whose integral from negative to positive infinity is a non-zero constant?

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{\pi}$. Showing the exact value is non trivial, but the integrand is continous and strictly positive, hence the integral over any interval $[-M,M]$ is strictly positive, and so the same must be true the integral over the entire line. For a more elementary example, consider $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$.

Comment: *Any* strictly positive function will have $\int_{-\infty}^\infty > 0$ (maybe $+\infty$).

Comment: The statement that $\int f = 0$ for $f(x)=k/(x^2+a)$ is obviously false (except for *k* = 0) -- this integral **IS** equal to a positive constant (for *k*, *a* > 0). I first thought that OP wanted *x* instead of *k*, but that gives integrals that would diverge on each half-space. So I really don't know what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}dx>0$ since $e^{-x^{2}}$ is Schwartz and nowhere nozero.